# How to search in array of objects - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having issues searching in an array of objects. Basically what my page needs to do is to create a new "client" using information entered by me, such as Full name, User name, Email and Password. Each one of these clients are objects in an array as you can see below.

```
var clientlist = [{"username":"John","fullname":"John Doe",
"email":"john.doe@hotmail.com","type":"client","password":"jdoe2"},
```

This client is already created in my js file, what I need to do is to create a new object to add to this array with this same structure. For example,

```
var clientlist = [{"username":"Peter","fullname":"Peter Jones",
"email":"peter.jones@hotmail.com","type":"client","password":"pjones1"},
```

I have written the code but it doesn't work properly, I cannot seem to search for the username to see if the username that I am adding already exists, it may be a syntax mistake. I will leave my complete code below and thanks in advance for the assistance!.

```
var clientlist = [{"username":"John","fullname":"John Doe",
"email":"john.doe@hotmail.com","type":"client","password":"jdoe2"},

var Client = {};

function NewClient(){
    var found;
    var user = $("#username").val();

    for (var i = 0; i < clientlist.length; i++) {
        if (clientlist[i] == user) {
            found = true;
        }else{
            found = false;
        }
    }

    if (found == true){
        $("#msj").html("User already exists!");
    }
    else if(found == false){
        Client["fullname"] = $("#fullname").val();
        Client["username"] = user;
        Client["email"] = $("#email").val();
        Client["type"] = "client";
        Client["password"] = $("#password").val();

        clientlist[clientlist.length] = Client;

        $("#msj").html("New client has been created");
    }
}
```

Comment: you better add your html markup also, ideally with jsfiddle link

Comment: You can always use `Array.prototype.findIndex()` or `Array.prototype.find()` to search object structures in an array however i would advise using a unique id per user and assign them as properties and the value of the id property can be your user object.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems with your `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < clientlist.length; i++) {
    if (clientlist[i] == user) {
    found = true;
}else{
    found = false;
}
```

So what are we working with? `clientlist` is array so `clientlist[i]` is an element of that array...which happens to be an object.

`user` value is a string so there is no way to equate a string to object in the `if`.

Correction there would be to inspect the correct property value in object:

```
if (clientlist[i].username == user) {
```

Next problem is that the loop keeps going even if a match is found. As loop continues `found` will be updated for each iteration. Thus `found` will only be set based on the very last object in array regardless if a match was already determined.

To correct this could put that `for` loop in a function so it breaks the loop by returning `true` if match is found. Alternative would be use other array methods like `Array.prototype.some()` which returns a boolean based on conditional in callback. Or use `break` if a match is found to prevent loop continuing.

`break` will be simplest to plugin to the code so final would be

```
for (var i = 0; i < clientlist.length; i++) {
    if (clientlist[i].username == user) {
    found = true;
    break;// quit loop since we found a match
}else{
    found = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, although it didn't quite work. I used Firebug to inpect how the object looks like and the value of User is " " instead of being lets say John. Any ideas?

Comment: Well that would be additional steps ...validate the input before going through looking for match. Not sure where you are calling `NewClient()`. If it is running on page load is a problem since user won't have entered anything yet

Comment: After all the text fields for fullname, username and such, there is a button that runs this function using `$("#btn").click(NewClient);` , "btn" is the button id.

Comment: Would need to see a demo that reproduces problem. Wouldn't take much to put basic html/script into jsfiddle.net to be able to test it and tweak it

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
for (var i = 0; i < clientlist.length; i++) {
    if (clientlist[i] == user) {
        found = true;
    }else{
       found = false;
    }
}
```

to

```
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < clientlist.length; i++) {
    if (clientlist[i].username == user) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: think var found should be false as default and only get set true for a match

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#some` for this: It lets you run a callback against each entry in an array and determine if it matches a condition. `some` stops and returns `true` the first time you return a truthy value from the callback, or returns `false` if no calls to the callback return a truthy value.

So:

```
if (clientlist.some(function(entry) { return entry.username === user; })) {
    $("#msj").html("User already exists");
} else {
    // ...add the user...
}
```

That's more concise with ES2015+ arrow functions:

```
if (clientlist.some(entry => entry.username === user)) {
    $("#msj").html("User already exists");
} else {
    // ...add the user...
}
```

Also note that you don't want to reuse the same `Client` object each time, because on the next add, you'll just change the existing object's properties. Instead, create a new object each time:

```
clientlist.push({
    username: user,
    fullname: $("#fullname").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    type: "client",
    password: $("#password").val()
});
```

```js
var clientlist = [{"username":"John","fullname":"John Doe",
"email":"john.doe@hotmail.com","type":"client","password":"jdoe2"}];

function NewClient() {
    var user = $("#username").val();
    if (clientlist.some(function(entry) { return entry.username === user; })) {
        $("#msj").html("User already exists");
    } else {
      clientlist.push({
        username: user,
        fullname: $("#fullname").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        type: "client",
        password: $("#password").val()
      });
      $("#username, #fullname, #email, #password").val("");
      $("#msj").html("New client has been created");
    }
}
$("#btn").on("click", NewClient);
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    Username: <input type="text" id="username">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Fullname: <input type="text" id="fullname">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Email: <input type="text" id="email">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Password: <input type="password" id="password">
  </label>
</div>
<div><input type="button" id="btn" value="Add"></div>
<div id="msj"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```